# Creating a training subset in Sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a training subset from my text data I load with `load_files` in `sklearn` like this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
categories = ['cat_1', 'cat_2']
corpus=load_files(container_path='...container_folder', description=None, load_content=True, encoding='utf-8', categories=categories, shuffle=True, decode_error='ignore', random_state=42)
X = corpus.data
y = corpus.target
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

This seems to work fine. Then I'm trying to follow the workflow as in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html, but when I enter the very first line as in example:

```
print (X_train.target_names)
```

I get the error:

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'target_names'"

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but can please anyone explain me what is wrong with this?

Comment: That `target_names` is a column of pandas DataFrame which is loaded in that link you gave. In your case, the `sklearn.load_files` is not loading the dataFrame, but a simple list for X. So you may not use `target_names` on it.

Comment: Its stated on the [`load_files()` documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) that "To use text files in a scikit-learn classification or clustering algorithm, you will need to use the sklearn.feature_extraction.text module to build a feature extraction transformer that suits your problem."

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the reply. However I don't understand. If I run 
print (corpus.target_names)

(so after applying load_files), the output is correct

Comment: Yes, thats correct. `corpus` is a DataFrame. But you yourself assigned `X = corpus.data`. So now X is an array which dont have that column anymore. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how do I split the data into subsets then? I'm really really grateful for your help, sorry to bother!

Comment: Are you asking about the `train_test_split`. That parts come after you preprocess your text data and convert it to a form usable by the scikit-learn (Numerical data only). At that time, use the `train_test_split` to split it into parts to train your model. If you want to simply divide your data before that, you can simply use the python indexing scheme ( `corpus[startIndex:endIndex]`). Or do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: I think I figured it all out, thank you so much!